# How to use xargs -P 20 with curl and list of hosts

Tags: bash, curl, xargs

One more nube's question..
I have a script which is checking hosts from list one by one for http response. How to upgrade it to multitrhead using xargs or other method?

```
#!/bin/bash
response="200"
cat list.txt | while read string
do
test=$(curl -I --path-as-is -s -k "http://"$string"/index.html" | head -n1)
if grep -q "response" <<< "$test"; then
echo $string " has response " $response
fi
done
```

Comment: If you have a recent version of curl (7.66+), you can use the [`--parallel` and `--parallel-max`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--parallel-max) command line options to do multiple parallel requests. (You probably don't have a sufficiently recent version as I write this comment (Jan. 2020), because the [stable Debian package](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/curl) is currently v7.64. But in the future this feature will be more widely available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code snippet would do it (note the exact `response_code` comparison against `200`):

```
code=200
xargs -P20 -I@ sh -c "test \$(curl -I -s -w "%{response_code}" http://@/index.html -o/dev/null) -eq $code && echo @ has code $code" < list.txt
```

If you'd rather prefer grepping for it, then do:

```
code=200
xargs -P20 -I@ sh -c "curl -I -s http://@/index.html | head -1 | grep -qw $code && echo @ has code $code" < list.txt
```

Then a slightly more optimized one, allowing to specify both parallelism (`-P20`) while also allowing each curl invocation to handle more than just 1 URL (`-n4`, less forking):

```
code=200
xargs -n4 -P20 -I@ curl -I -s -w "%{response_code}: @\n" http://@/index.html -o/dev/null | egrep "^$code:" < list.txt
```

Comment: it shows "sh: 1: test: not found" even if 2nd ip in list.txt has code 200

Comment: Probably change from `sh -c` to `bash -c` would help.